Multi tenancy for consumer facing application
I'm building a consumer-facing application using Django and DRF that will have user accounts. I'd like to integrate some multi-tenancy into it so that all data is separated by tenant(user). I know that I could simply filter by user in queryset but I feel that this approach is a bit more secure. I am also aware of the django-tenant and django-tenant-schema pkgs but I'd like to try and avoid outside pkgs if possible.
Basically where there is a main tenants-table all other tables have a foreign-key pointing to that table. Does that sound right?
So basically something like this:
class Tenant(models.Model):
    tenant_id = f'{...}'
    ....


from tenant.models import Tenant
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = f'{....}'
    tenant_id = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, ...)
    ...



from tenant.models import Tenant
class Profile(models.Model):
    profile_id = f'{...}'
    user_id = f'{...}'
    tenant_id = models.ForeignKey(Tenant, ...)
    ...


Yes. You assign users to tenants and later make sure that query is filtered by user tenant.

That is indeed one way to do multi-tenancy. django-tenants has a concise summary of how one might approach multi-tenancy:

1 - Isolated Approach: Separate Databases. Each tenant has its own database.
2 - Semi Isolated Approach: Shared Database, Separate Schemas. One database for all tenants, but one schema per tenant.
3 - Shared Approach: Shared Database, Shared Schema. All tenants share the same database and schema. There is a main tenant-table, where all other tables have a foreign key pointing to.

#3 is the one you are talking about.
However, you said this:

I'd like to integrate some multi-tenancy into it so that all data is separated by tenant(user). I know that I could simply filter by user in queryset but I feel that this approach is a bit more secure.

If you are saying that a tenant is equivalent to a single user, then your conclusion is wrong. The foreignkey pointing to User and the foreignkey pointing to Tenant serve the exact same purpose, and filtering data on tenant is not (even a little bit) more secure than filtering on user - they are exactly identical in form, function and security.
There is no difference at all, security-wise, between the following two calls:
customers = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)

customers = Customer.objects.filter(tenant=user.tenant)

If more than a single user can belong to the same tenant, then you might need a Tenant table. But for the sake of clarity: that's for function, not for security.
If leaking data between tenants is your concern, extending the foreignkey chain isn't going to have any impact (except make your application harder to maintain, which in turn can make it more difficult for you to make sure everything works as it should).

I'm not using a ForeignKey field, I'm using a OneToOneField. That way one tenant is equal to exactly one user. Not sure if that makes a difference or not?

No. atleast not in the favor of the tenant setup - having OneToOne actually cements the redundancy of Tenant in my opinion. Do you have a specific reason for why you think it would be more secure? For instance, in your view, what is the difference security-wise between filtering on the user and the user's tenant?

I might be misunderstanding this whole tenant thing! I'm from the JS world where 3rd party pkgs can be a very painful solution. I really want to try to keep this simple but I do need a way to securely separate user's data. I did see read some posts on Reddit that mentioned having a tenants table where all other tables have a foreign key pointing to it. I also saw some the shared db and schema and using a Model Manager to ensure that db queries only return the user's data. Do you still recommend Django Tenants for this or would that Model Manager strategy be viable as well?

After some more reading and hopefully better understanding of the concept, I think I'm going to go with the model Manager strategy. I know python better than I know Django, so I'd rather KISS until I know Django better.

For future answer seekers, I accept the answer bc it did help me understand that multi-tenant may not be the way to go

The concept of a "tenant" is a little floaty, but it generally makes more sense in scenarios where you have a workspace or an organization, which can have multi-user memberships. In such a case, the workspace/organization is the tenant. In single-user scenarios, the user is the tenant.

The "model manager" strategy can also work, it's just a shorthand for writing the .filter() calls I showed in the examples. But it also seems a little redundant unless your queries are very complex or involve a lot of users at the same time. Writing model_manager.get_data(user) versus model.objects.filter(user=user) seems much the same case to me, in terms of how easy or difficult it is to accidentally leak data. But it's also no problem to do it in that way - if that's what you feel comfortable with, go for it.

thanks for the help, I think you helped me make a better choice!
